# What is the difference between prepare_for_model and encode_plus?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

What is the difference between [prepare_for_model](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.prepare_for_model) and [encode_plus](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v2.11.0/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus)? A model needs input ids, type ids and attention mask. So what are special tokens? And which function should be used?